# convertion into integer linear program for Ising spin state problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to model the Ising spin state problem into Integer linear program and find the optimal ground state using lp_solve. (This is just a miniature version of Ising state problem)

$$
maximise: \sum J_{ij}S_{i}S_{j}
$$
$$
-1\leq J_{ij} \leq 1
$$
$$
S_{i},S_{j} \epsilon (-1,1)
$$
Value of $J_{ij}$ is given.
The goal is to find optimal values of $S_{i}$ to maximise the value. 
For ex:
$J_{12}=1, J_{13}=-1, J_{23}=-1$. One of the solutions for maximum energy is 3 with $S_{1}=1, S_{2}=1, S_{3}=-1$.

I am finding it difficult to convert this into integer linear program.

This is my initial approach for the conversion.
I tried to take an aditional variable $X_{i}$ and convert this program as
$$
maximise: \sum X_{i}
$$
$ if((S_{i}=-1 or S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=-1) \implies X_{i}=1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 or S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=1) \implies X_{i}=-1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 and S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=-1) \implies X_{i}=-1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 and S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=1) \implies X_{i}=1 $

I dont know if this approach is correct or not. Even i dont know how to convert this to linear program.
Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a binary quadratic program, not a binary linear program.

Comment: I am trying to find the ground state using lp_solve. lp_solve cannot handle Quadratic terms. Is there any way to convert this problem into a linear program.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Normally I would say "of course not!" but the fact that every single quantity is $\pm 1$ suggests I had better reserve judgement.

Comment: I do think the other commenters are right. The right way to solve this is using a binary quadratic programming engine. However I do know that it is possible to convert this to a mixed integer linear program, and when I get home and finish editing my answer I will post it.

Comment: I posted an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1210586/52878).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the paper "Using a Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming Solver for the Unconstrained Quadratic 0-1 Problem" by Alain Billionnet and Sourour Elloumi. They mention there that the binary quadratic problem

$$\min \left\{ x^T Q x + c^Tx : x \in \{0,1\}^n \right\},$$

where $Q$ is a symmetric matrix with diagonal entries all zero, is equivalent to the mixed integer linear programming problem

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\min & \sum_{i} c_i x_i + \sum_{i < j} 2Q_{ij} y_{ij} \\
\text{s.t.} 
&  y_{ij} \leq x_i & i < j, & Q_{ij} < 0 \\
&  y_{ij} \leq x_j & i < j, & Q_{ij} < 0 \\
&  y_{ij} \geq x_i + x_j - 1 & i < j, & Q_{ij} > 0 \\
&  y_{ij} \geq 0 & i < j, & Q_{ij} \neq 0\\
&  x_i \in \{0, 1\}.
\end{array}
$$

Since you are interested in solving the Ising spin state problem, you should also check out the chapter "Computing Exact Ground States of Hard Ising Spin Glass Problems by Branch-and-Cut" by Frauke Liers, Michael Jünger, Gerhard Reinelt, and Giovanni Rinaldi.

Also check out the paper "Solving Max-Cut to optimality by intersecting semidefinite and polyhedral relaxations" by Franz Rendl, Giovanni Rinaldi, and Angelika Wiegele that describes the semidefinite based branch-and-bound software [Biq Mac](http://biqmac.uni-klu.ac.at) and its performance on solving Ising spin state problems.

Finally, you can try [BiqCrunch](http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/BiqCrunch/) which is another semidefinite based branch-and-bound solver that is capable of solving Ising spin state problems.